# Can I use a .pkl file even if it gives me a DepreciationWarning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means, python-3.7

I'm working through someone else's poorly documented code (it uses tf-idf to find clusters of documents), and I came across this:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

#joblib.dump(km,  'doc_cluster.pkl')
km = joblib.load('doc_cluster.pkl')
clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
```

It's supposed to unpickle doc_cluster.pkl, but when I run it, I get a DepreciationWarning that says that the file was generated with a joblib version less than 0.10, and it requests that I regenerate the file. However, I can't do that, because I didn't create doc_cluster.pkl. So is it ok to just move forward and ignore the warning, or will that mess things up down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deprecation warning is *just a warning*, and loading succeeds. The pickle file is still being loaded and supported, at least in this version of sklearn (which bundles the 3rd party [`joblib` project](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). A future version of `joblib` may stop supporting that specific format, but that hasn't happened yet.

You can re-create the pickle file with the current version, simply by dumping the same object back to disk:

```
km = joblib.load('doc_cluster.pkl')
joblib.dump(km, 'doc_cluster.pkl', compress=True)
```

Also see the [`joblib` *persistence* documentation](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html).

Alternatively, you could suppress the warning, by using a warning filter. You can set filters in the [`PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS), with the [`-W` command-lne switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w) (I'd use the string `ignore::DeprecationWarning:sklearn.externals.joblib`), or by using the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) directly:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(
    "ignore", category=DeprecationWarning,
    module=r'sklearn\.externals\.joblib'
)
```

Comment: I used the recreating the pickle file solution, and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Deprecation Warnings are only warnings that tell you that the code your using has been updated in the package and that there is a better / more efficient way of writing your program. The package still supports it, just know that in a future update of the package the old functions might now be supported.